# VSCode Terminal alters the $PATH

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have coreutils installed on macos with /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin prepended to the path which works in the regular terminal.

When I use the VSCode terminal, it prepends /bin to the $PATH which breaks the usage of GNU coreutils.
Why does it do so and how do I stop it from changing the $PATH?

Comment: Check your terminal.integrated.env.osx setting

Comment: @ikkentim it's empty

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, the default settings have:

```
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [
    "-l"
  ],
```

it needs to be overriden with an empty list.